# What is this bicycle?

Tags: identify-this-bike

This is a ladies step through frame with 26x1 3/8 tyres. It has the fleur de lys sign on the front and says nervex on the bb. Single speed and has cable brakes [image]

Comment: A standard bicycle that may give you great joy but that will require a great deal of work to take it out of its sorry state of neglect and corrosion.

Comment: The letters cut into the chainset might tell you the answer.

Comment: @JoeK is right - a close photo of the chainring will show something.  All I can read is a B or an R in the vertical,

Comment: The chainring has the letters R,H,A maybe not in that combination

Comment: I have searched the letter and I haven’t found anything yet

Comment: Bog-standard mixte, likely from the 50s or 60s.

Comment: I would have to disagree because it is pretty well built. I have other old bikes e.g. a royal enfield, dunelt, Rudge, hercules and raleighs and this looks better build quality than those apart from the Rudge.